# Can not get serving URL for images from Google Cloud Storage -> "NOT_IMAGE: Failed to read image"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I first save an image to Google Cloud Storage also setting the mime type to something like "image/png" and name it randomly with the file ending e.g. ".png". The files seem to be stored correctly. I can see them in the datastore viewer:

[image]

But if I try to load it again with the `com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService` and call `ImagesService.getServigUrl()`, it throws the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NOT_IMAGE: Failed to read image
```

So this seems to think it is not an image. But why? It has the mime typ set, it has the file ending. The code looks like this:

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(crop, oldImage);

final GcsService gcsService =
        GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());

AppIdentityService appservice =  com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();

GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename(appservice.getDefaultGcsBucketName(), Long.toString(random.nextLong(), 36)+"."+newImage.getFormat().toString().toLowerCase());

GcsFileOptions gcsOptions = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
  .mimeType("image/"+newImage.getFormat().toString().toLowerCase())
  .acl("public-read").build();

GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
        gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, gcsOptions);

ObjectOutputStream oout =
    new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
oout.writeObject(newImage.getImageData());
oout.close();


ServingUrlOptions suo = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName("/gs/"+fileName.getBucketName()+"/"+fileName.getObjectName()).secureUrl(true);
String s = imagesService.getServingUrl(suo);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Are you running your code from the Dev server or Live? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868646/google-app-engine-imagesservice-getservingurl-fails-to-read-image

Comment: Yes, it is the dev server. But for the Blobstore on the on the other hand it works on the dev server for me. The linked question has no solution..

Comment: If you read the comments it says it worked when he tried it live "It seems getServingUrl fails only on the App Engine test server " Try deploying it.

Comment: I also faced this issue and found the solution on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778367/photo-dont-uploaded-correctly-gcs-app-engine/34069463#34069463

Answer (score 0):

Might be it is not a image mime type you have uploaded,check your mime type of the uploaded file.